# Softkinetic node StreamingException with senz3D

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I try to use a Creative Senz3D with the softkinetic node from https://github.com/ipa320/softkinetic.
I have installed the DepthSense SDK and I can view the image stream with the sample program from the SDK. But I get a "DepthSense::StreamingException" when I start the softkinetic node. I get this error with every color_frame_format setting. If I disable the color image in the config the nodes starts without error. So it has something to do with the color image stream. I use ros indigo on a system with ubuntu 14.04.2 and tried USB 3.0 and 2.0 ports.

Here is the console output from softkinetic_camera_ds325.launch:

```
pmsr@rts-sim-3:~/ros_workspace/catkin_ws/src/ros_depthsense_camera/launch$ roslaunch softkinetic_camera softkinetic_camera_ds325.launch 
... logging to /home/pmsr/.ros/log/3418d49a-0549-11e5-a9b4-d8cb8a4f9f37/roslaunch-rts-sim-3-13950.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://rts-sim-3:44319/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro: indigo
 * /rosversion: 1.11.13
 * /softkinetic_camera/camera_link: softkinetic_camer...
 * /softkinetic_camera/color_compression: MJPEG
 * /softkinetic_camera/color_frame_format: WXGA
 * /softkinetic_camera/color_frame_rate: 25
 * /softkinetic_camera/confidence_threshold: 200
 * /softkinetic_camera/depth_frame_format: QVGA
 * /softkinetic_camera/depth_frame_rate: 25
 * /softkinetic_camera/depth_mode: close
 * /softkinetic_camera/enable_color: True
 * /softkinetic_camera/enable_depth: True
 * /softkinetic_camera/min_neighbours: 50
 * /softkinetic_camera/search_radius: 0.05
 * /softkinetic_camera/use_radius_outlier_filter: False
 * /softkinetic_camera/use_voxel_grid_filter: False
 * /softkinetic_camera/voxel_grid_size: 0.03

NODES
  /
    softkinetic_camera (softkinetic_camera/softkinetic_bringup_node)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [13962]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to 3418d49a-0549-11e5-a9b4-d8cb8a4f9f37
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [13975]
started core service [/rosout]
process[softkinetic_camera-2]: started with pid [13992]
[ INFO] [1432824767.747549238]: Number of Devices found: 1
Argument Exception: argument "node": context already has control over the node
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'DepthSense::StreamingException'
  what():  VIDIOC_STREAMON failed (No space left on device)
[softkinetic_camera-2] process has died [pid 13992, exit code -6, cmd /home/pmsr/ros_workspace/catkin_ws/devel/lib/softkinetic_camera/softkinetic_bringup_node 0 __name:=softkinetic_camera __log:=/home/pmsr/.ros/log/3418d49a-0549-11e5-a9b4-d8cb8a4f9f37/softkinetic_camera-2.log].
log file: /home/pmsr/.ros/log/3418d49a-0549-11e5-a9b4-d8cb8a4f9f37/softkinetic_camera-2*.log
```

What else can I try to get the node working?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/210915/softkinetic-node-streamingexception-with-senz3d/) by [splash](https://answers.ros.org/users/22722/splash/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-06-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-06-10**:
Please report bugs/issues at the `ipa320/softkinetic` [issue tracker](https://github.com/ipa320/softkinetic/issues).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sometimes it's a permission problem. Or a lib problem.

Here the same Streaming Exeption is given:

http://www.softkinetic.com/support/Forum/aft/1702

I've solved it by checking this:

(From the link)

> I export the DepthSense Library with
> "export
> LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/softkinetic/DepthSenseSDK/lib/", with "echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH" I get
> this line:
>
> /opt/softkinetic/DepthSenseSDK/lib/.
>
> All seem ok!

Then you should look into your /opt/softkinetic/DepthSenseSDK/lib folder

Mine looks like this:

```
libDepthSensePlugins.so@    libDepthSensePlugins.so.1.4.5  libDepthSense.so.1@     libturbojpeg.so  libusb-1.0.so.0
libDepthSensePlugins.so.1@  libDepthSense.so@              libDepthSense.so.1.4.5  libusb-1.0.so    libusb-1.0.so.0.1.0
```

The "libDepthSensePlugins.so" file links to the "ibDepthSensePlugins.so.1", same thing with the libDepthSense files.

I remember that i had to create that one myself to fix an issue. Can't seem to find the documentation where that solution is found. But credits go to him :-p

To create the links

```
ln -s /opt/softkinetic/DepthSenseSDK/lib/libDepthSensePlugins.so.1 /opt/softkinetic/DepthSenseSDK/lib/libDepthSensePlugins.so
ln -s /opt/softkinetic/DepthSenseSDK/lib/libDepthSense.so.1 /opt/softkinetic/DepthSenseSDK/lib/libDepthSense.so
```

---

Originally posted by [anonymous24903](https://answers.ros.org/users/24903/anonymous24903/) with karma: 20 on 2015-11-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0